# Simple phrase passed from google assistent as a webhook, then node red logic

Tags: node-red, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I have node red sercer that handles my home automation.
I have also 3 google speakers (1 hub a 2 mini).
I want to be able to say some phrases in google assistent, and he should pass them as a webhook to  designated URL. Node red will do the rest.
Node red part is easy, but I cant figure out google assisten part.
I can do that with IFTTT but I dont want to use it, raw google integration seems to be better practice.
Can You help me with that?

Comment: This question is far to vague to be answered. There are multiple nodes that already support Google Assistant integration for Smart home control. Otherwise you will have to read the Google docs and have a go. If you get stuck you can then you can ask specific questions.

Comment: If you could explain what about the Google Assistant part you can't figure out, then we could help with that.

Comment: What I cant figure out is how to learn my google assistat/home to catch certain phrases, and if he  catch them, to send for example a webhook to my node red server. Norde red part I have already done. Now im using IFTTT simple phrase, it catches phrase "door camera", passed is as webhook to my node red server, and server does the rest. Im simply want to  ecxlude IFTTT part and do it trought google itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't teach your Google Assistant device itself to respond to a phrase and send it to your webhook. You can create an [Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview#top_of_page) for Google Assistant that functions just like an app on your phone. You teach this action to respond to certain phrases when someone interacts with your action.

You can choose between two types of Actions:

- Conversational Actions: Designed around a conversation.
- Smart Home Action: Designed around command based interactions and smart home devices

Depending on which types on conversations you wish to make, you can choose one or the other. By the sound your description a conversational action would be preferred as you are only sending data to a webhook and you aren't interacting with a smart home device directly.

To send the data, your Action can also use a [webhook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder). It can't directly connect to your node red webhook, because the actions requires code that handles
the information from the device. Using one of Googles [code libraries](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=builder#development_options) you can then make HTTP calls or whatever you need for Node Red via code and make Node Red handle it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I will check this out